# What is the easiest way to convert MPEG video to FLV format?

Tags: video, video-conversion, flv, mpeg

I have MPEG video (.mpg) that I would like to convert to FLV format for use in Flash players.  What is the easiest (idiot-proof) way to do this on a Windows machine?

Comment: Easiest? Get someone else to do it ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[FFmpeg](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/ffmpeg) is available for windows (even with a GUI!) and does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I used the WinFF GUI from the site you linked to, it worked just great.

Answer (score 4):

You could use Zamar (http://zamzar.com/) which is online, or Any Video Converter (http://www.any-video-converter.com/products/for_video_free/).

I've used Any Video Converter and it works well. It contains components of FFMpeg and MPlayer in a very nice, easy to use interface. You can download it here: http://www.download.com/Any-Video-Converter/3000-2194_4-10661456.html

Answer (score 2):

[Mediacoder](http://mediacoder.sourceforge.net) is a nice program to convert almost anything with a nice intuitive graphical interface.

Answer (score 0):

Use [FLV Converter](http://www.flv-converter.org/). It has both standard and portable versions, and it's freeware.

[image: img]