# flv video convertor

Tags: video, flv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the easiest way to convert MPEG video to FLV format?](https://superuser.com/questions/10035/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-convert-mpeg-video-to-flv-format)

which is the best flv video convertor

Comment: prakasam, Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  You can find help for general computer-related questions at superuser.com.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the easiest way to convert MPEG video to FLV format?](http://superuser.com/questions/10035/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-convert-mpeg-video-to-flv-format). Without more details about "converting from what, to what", voting to close as duplicate. The accepted answer there should anyway be valid for most formats.

Answer (score 1):

Try [FLV Converter](http://www.flv-converter.org/). It has both standard and portable versions. It's freeware.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of Any Video Converter.  It's free (though also nagware, but not too bad) and lets you convert from a lot of formats to any other format, with granular controls for sound and video quality, as well as the ability to set up batch jobs.

http://www.any-video-converter.com/products/for_video_free/